# MediaPlayer, RecyclerAdapter shows a few play buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Recycle view should show a few songs and one button play, but instead of this it shows a few songs and a few buttons play, seems like I do something wrong.

I initialized `songTitle` `TextView` and `testButtonPlay` `button` in `sound_template.xml` layout.

If I'm initializing `testButtonPlay` in my activity with RecyclerView I'm getting error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void
>   android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

```
class RecyclerSoundScreenAdapter(val context: Context,
                                 val song: List<Sound>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerSoundScreenAdapter.Holder>() {
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var currentPlayingSound: Sound? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(song[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return song.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sound_template, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)
    }

    fun releaseMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer?.release()
        mediaPlayer = null
    }

    inner class Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(sound: Sound) = with(itemView) {
            songTitle.text = sound.title
            testButtonPlay.setOnClickListener {
                if (currentPlayingSound == sound) {
                    if (mediaPlayer?.isPlaying == true) {
                        mediaPlayer?.pause()
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer?.start()
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mediaPlayer?.isPlaying == true) {
                        mediaPlayer?.release()
                        mediaPlayer = null
                    }
                    currentPlayingSound = sound
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound.resId)
                    mediaPlayer?.start()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see initialization of `songTitle` and `testButtonPlay` in your code. Are you using kotlin android extension?

Comment: @AndreiTanana yes, I'm using kotlin extension without initialization.

Comment: So, please, check that you are using imports from correct layouts. Also, your `Holder` should extend `LayoutContainer`. You can read about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#layoutcontainer-support

Comment: Seems like I need to initialize another media player that will be able to work with another activity and with that `play` button. Then I will be able to click on the song title to play or pause it and I will be able to do the same by clicking `play` button. But where I should initialize it? In another activity where I call this adapter and where I have another layout container with RecyclerView?